# Override UserId in Segment Analytics

Tags: analytics, segment-io

Basic question here related to Segment analytics. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find a good answer after a fair bit of searching so turning here.

I have a couple of analytics events that need to be logged against multiple users, e.g. "Matched"

Is there a way to override the "userId" property on a event without calling identify again (which would override the user for all future events & thus risks race conditions or blocking on analytics)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with `analytics.js`. If you need to send events for another `userId` than the one you had called `.identify()` with, you should use a server side library to send that event.

All server side libraries will need a `userId` defined so it would be a good place to send that particular event.

Also Segment just got a brand new [community](https://help.segment.com/hc/en-us/community/topics) to post these questions fyi.